# login with facebook for php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

please tell me a good tutorial to learn 
php mysql 
login with facebook

Does login with facebook use the facebook api or the facebook sdk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this [TUTORIAL](http://www.joeyrivera.com/2010/facebook-graph-api-app-easy-w-php-sdk/)

There is one problem with his `config.php` file.Rather than using `if(is_null($facebook->getUser()))...` use following code for checking if user already exists.

```
try{
    $me = $facebook->api('/me');
$error='no';
    }
    catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        $error='yes';
        $perms=array('req_perms' => 'user_status,publish_stream,user_photos,email,status_update,friends_status,export_stream');
        echo"<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL=".$facebook->getLoginUrl($perms,$cancel,$next,$display)."'>";
        exit;           
      }
    if($error!='yes'){//already logged in use normally
            }
```

Comment: the beginning of this tutorial:  <br>                                NOTE: This post was written using Facebook’s PHP SDK version 2.1.2. Since this post was made, the PHP SDK has changed and some of the process that are explained below may have changed as well. At some point I’ll have to revisit this post and update it but at this time just keep in mind of the above.<br>  Are you sure it works for php mysql with your config.php change.

Comment: A lot of things has change. Although it still works for me since but then again I use only basic user information. You will be able to modify the usage in this api after you are able to understand it's methods. To check out the changes, us this [tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) which shows you the data recieved and the form it is recieved.

Comment: As for the `config.php` his code only causes some cases

Comment: update:you need to update the library files since the sdk used in the tutorial has been depreciated.Simply replace the files `library` folder with the files in `src` folder present [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk)

Answer (score -1):

You should use the [SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/). Take a look at the documentation, it is clear and well explained.